# Wiring from house to garage

Tags: wiring

What size wire 125’ to garage,will have 50 amp welding machine and led lights only use at the same time.Plan to use underground cable.

Comment: I take it this is a detached garage, correct?  Also, are you *buying* this 50A welder, or do you already have it sitting in front of you?

Comment: Is it a 240V-only welder, or does it need a neutral?  Will you NEVER power any 120V devices out in the garage (or do you already have a 120V circuit coming out there?)

Comment: As Bob the Builder points out, can you answer: Detached or attached garage?  What is the total distance of the wiring run? What is the amp capacity of your current service/loadcenter?  What else do you foresee running in the garage at the same time as the welder? Honestly without detailed info you won't get an answer (at least not here, other forums will  cheerfully turn insufficient data into a terrible answer, as can Home Depot employees).